# Which thread pool manager is recommended for Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, threadpool

I only know of [`Thread::Pool`](http://p3rl.org/Thread::Pool) which is apparently not supported in recent Perl versions, and [`Thread::Pool::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/Thread::Pool::Simple) which lacks almost any documentation.

So which thread pool manager can I use under Perl v5.10.1 or and higher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How can I install `Thread::Pool` from CPAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742793/how-can-i-install-threadpool-from-cpan/3755350#3755350).

Answer (score -1):

Use `Thread::Pool`. I found that `Thread::Pool::Simple` is so slow that you gain nothing from using it.